# How to call ng-repeat when data is populated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to generate multiple divs based on an array which gets populated asynchronously.

```
<div ng-controller=visCtrl>
    {{categories}} <!-- prints nothing -->
    <div ng-repeat="item in categories">
        some test text

    </div>
</div>
```

where categories is populated after some time.

But there is no div generated as the `categories` is empty at the time when it is called.

How can I generate the multiple divs?

Here is the controller code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.utils']);
//some lines clipped in between
myApp.controller('visCtrl', function($scope) {
    d3.csv($scope.dataFile,function(d){
        $scope.opendata=d;  



        var obj=$scope.opendata[0];
        $scope.categories=[];
        for(var key in obj){
            if(key!=="STATE/UT"&&key!=="DISTRICT"&&key!=="YEAR"){
                $scope.categories.push(key);
            }
        }
        console.log($scope.categories);

    });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the controller code what you have done?

Comment: We won't be able to tell unless you show us your controller code.

Comment: Show us your controller, this is a common behaviour on AngularJS. 
If your controller is performing something like : $scope.categories = items the your div will be populated properly

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code at all. You might want to check if categories have anything at all. If you are getting it from an API then most likely your api return `NULL` or if your populating categories somewhere within the code by your self then you must post the controller code to be able debug.

Comment: please see the controller code @JqueryKing

Comment: Make sure array length greater than 0 for categories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in categories">
    some test text
</div>
```

This code is fine. `ng-repeat` should change the DOM when `categories` changes. If it doesn't, then angular doesn't know about the changes.

First, make sure you assign to proper `categories` (the one on `$scope`, not a local variable or something).

Next, if you're populating it via jQuery AJAX call (for example), then it's out of angular's life cycle. You need to tell it that things changed, by calling `$scope.$apply()`. Read this, for example: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()

Comment: if he is using angulars $http, then its not outside of the angular scope and the changes should be applied automatically.

Comment: yeah, but I'd bet he uses jquery instead.

Comment: $apply works but it's the wrong answer. $apply is very rarely needed when the framework is used correctly.

Comment: yeah, at the time when this answer was posted, I didn't see the controller code.

Answer (score 2):

You've confused the d3 callback with the controller. When your ng-repeat fires, $scope.categories is undefined. Creating it later won't update ng-repeat. You need to have the array created in the controller. Then ng-repeat will watch that array and when it changes in the d3.csv() callback ng-repeat will update accordingly.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.utils']);
//some lines clipped in between
myApp.controller('visCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.categories=[];


    d3.csv($scope.dataFile,function(d){
        $scope.opendata=d;  

        $scope.categories.length = 0;

        var obj=$scope.opendata[0];
        for(var key in obj){
            if(key!=="STATE/UT"&&key!=="DISTRICT"&&key!=="YEAR"){
                $scope.categories.push(key);
            }
        }
        console.log($scope.categories);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment again for some reason. Anyway are you getting data in your console output? Why aren't you using any expressions to dump the data into the div? Try outputting something to see if it works.

Also you could try putting an item into your array when you instantiate it. That way if it still doesn't work, you'll know your theory about it binding before you populate it isn't quite right.

Comment: Don't delete your post

Comment: Ah that was why. I can comment again now. Thanks JqueryKing. Vishal, try my other suggestions above.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller=visCtrl>
    {{categories}} <!-- prints nothing -->
    <div ng-if="categories && categories.length > 0">
        <div ng-repeat="item in categories">
        some test text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

you could put the ng-if on the repeat but that seems unnecessary because it would go on all of them.

To be clear, this answers your question. But is most likely not your problem.

edit:

try putting a $scope.$apply after your loop.

```
for(var key in obj){
            if(key!=="STATE/UT"&&key!=="DISTRICT"&&key!=="YEAR"){
                $scope.categories.push(key);
            }
        }
$scope.$apply();
```

Comment: I think it won't make any difference in his case.

Comment: As i stated its not a solution to his problem, but rather the answer to his question.

Comment: Well then post a comment on his question suggesting an edit or clarification, not a bad answer?